# When does the prohibition against eating meat during the 9 Days start?

Tags: halacha, tisha-bav, nine-days

does the prohibition regarding eating meat start at night or in the morning?

If this is unclear... On Rosh Chodesh (the night of, the night we say yala ve yavo) can we have meet for dinner?

I know the day starts at night, but I'm not sure that I've ever heard of no meat the night of Rosh Chodesh.

Please source all answers.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2114/meat-on-rosh-chodesh-of-9-days

Comment: Not an answer, but we just had a large bbq, and we all made sure to finish eating before sunset.  On the other hand, one of the people there asked why we were being careful since it was Rosh Chodesh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do have a good argument, since the reasoning for starting the restrictions from Rosh Chodesh is the ominous month of Av, which has no standing without the sanctification of the Sanhedrin, which was done in the day.

However, in these matters everything is according to the custom.  The Magen Avraham (O.C. [551:26](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14327&st=&pgnum=264)) indicates that it starts at night.  Although he brings the public evening service as the starting point, while stating that some start at sunset, the custom in the United States considers sunset as the official start of the day.

Answer (score 3):

this issue depends on whether you are sefardi or ashkenazi. although a minority opinion holds that if one always has a meaty rosh chodesh seuda then he may do so on rosh chodesh av as well, however the vast majority of poskim - including the chayei adam (133,15) and mishna brura (551, 58) rule that one may not have meat on rosh chodesh itself.

yet, even the sefardi poskim who are machmir on the 9 days (the shulchan aruch cites 3 opinions with no ruling) hold that one may eat meat on rosh chodesh av itself - including the  ben ish chai (year 1 devarim 15)and kaf hachaim (551, 125 -126).