# Eating meat prepared for Shabbos on the 9 days

Tags: halacha, meat, nine-days

Someone said that his rabbi (maybe Sifardi) said that it is ok to eat leftover meat (dishes) from Shabbos during the 9 days.

Is this true?
Source please.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2114/759

Comment: R. Aryeh Leibowitz discusses this pretty comprehensively: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/904367/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/ten-minute-halacha-eating-shabbos-leftovers-during-the-nine-days/

Answer (score 7):

The Birkei Yosef 551/6 brings those that permit it to be eaten.

However, the Magen Avraham 551/26, Prei Megadim 551/26, Derech Hachaim 9, Mishneh Berurah 551/56 and the Aruch Hashulchan 551/24, write that it may not be eaten.

I don't know about the minhag of  the Sefradim.

Comment: Do you know the minhag of the Ashkenazim?

Comment: http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=950&txtSearch=meat

Comment: @Ploni your link is a perfect answer

Comment: Why wouldn't baal tashchis be a bigger problem than meat during the 9 days?

Comment: @Dude 1 freezer, 2.when they are forbiden you will make sure you have no Leftovers, 3. passivity (not eating) is not ball tashchis 4. You can feed it to animals

Comment: @hazoriz - I might add 5) For the sake of remembering the Bet Hamikdash, we should be stringent in following rules of "sadness" during this period. The destruction of the Bet Hamikdash is a bigger deal than the destruction of food. 6) Find a hungry Gentile.

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed true although there aren't clear parameters (until when; only for seudah revi'it/melaveh Makkah, Sun. or later). The general permissibility is not a Sefard-Ashkenaz *mahloket*; it is a later-day "legal loophole" discussed by many Achronim; some were Sefardic and others were Ashkenazic.

Some Sefardim accepted this "loophole" as quoted in [the answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93980/15571) from פרי זהב and some Ashkenazim too accepted it: R. Zvi Elimelech of Dinov (Bne Yisaschar, Tammuz-Av 1:10) R. Menashe Klein ([Mishneh Halachot vol. 8 §219](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1880&pgnum=324)), R. Mordechai Winkler ([Levushe Mordechai vol. 3 OC §49](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=786&st=&pgnum=400&hilite=)).

For a more thorough discussion on this question see R. Ovadiah Yosef in Chazon Ovadiah Arba Taniyot (177ff.)