# Can you taste meat made for Shabbos of the Nine Days?

Tags: halacha, nine-days

I saw [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93979/9682) and was inspired to ask about the opposite case.

If one made a fleishig dish for Shabbos of the Nine Days, can he taste (and swallow) of the dish to make sure it tastes good? Since it’s for Shabbos, is that okay?

Comment: (Although this question is technically broader since not every Erev Shabbat in the nine days is Erev Shabbat Chazon.)